# Парс xml строки

Tags: xml, java, синтаксический-анализ

Добрый вечер. Люди подскажите самый простой способ парса XML такого типа на java. Количество данных может увеличиватся. А если будет пример, так вообще праздник)

Спасибо

```
<kontrKaches>
<kontrKach>
    <id>4</id>
    <datetime>2014-04-07</datetime>
    <fkKachestvo>Оценка качества обработки почвы дисковыми агрегатами
    </fkKachestvo>
    <fkPolia>124</fkPolia>
    <fkPersonal>Стапаненко Иван Иванович</fkPersonal>
    <content>1</content>
</kontrKach>
<kontrKach>
    <id>5</id>
    <datetime>2014-04-07</datetime>
    <fkKachestvo>Оценка качества культивации</fkKachestvo>
    <fkPolia>125</fkPolia>
    <fkPersonal>Антонова Василиса Михайловна</fkPersonal>
    <content>11</content>
</kontrKach>
</kontrKaches>
```

Comment: docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/xpath.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение: использовал DOM

```
        File fXmlFile = new File("file1.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("kontrKach");

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
            System.out.println("----------------------------\n");
            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

            System.out.println("id : "
                    + eElement.getElementsByTagName("id").item(0)
                            .getTextContent());
            System.out.println("datetime : "
                    + eElement.getElementsByTagName("datetime").item(0)
                            .getTextContent());
            System.out.println("fkKachestvo : "
                    + eElement.getElementsByTagName("fkKachestvo").item(0)
                            .getTextContent());
            System.out.println("fkPolia : "
                    + eElement.getElementsByTagName("fkPolia").item(0)
                            .getTextContent());
            System.out.println("fkPersonal : "
                    + eElement.getElementsByTagName("fkPersonal").item(0)
                            .getTextContent());
            System.out.println("content : "
                    + eElement.getElementsByTagName("content").item(0)
                            .getTextContent());

        }
```

подскажите как тему закрыть?)